# JSLint error checking as a build step

Tags: javascript, msbuild, msbuild-task, jslint, csproj

I would like to run JSlint against my JS files in my web project and I was wondering if this can be made as part of the build step where in the build fails if and when there are js errors in the file. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is this http://sedodream.codeplex.com/ MSBuild extension which contains a JSLint task. It uses rather an old version of JSLint, but you can download the source and upgrade to the latest JSLint version.

You can also take a look at the author's blog to see how to integrate it to your build: 
[MSBuild + JSLint = Good Javascript](http://sedodream.com/2008/04/15/MSBuildJSLintGoodJavascript.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you can arrange for your build to invoke an external command, check out [jslint4java](http://code.google.com/p/jslint4java/).  It's a single jar file that can invoke jslint over a set of files for you (disclaimer: I am the author).

Comment: hmm,, im nt sure of runnin jar files.. i cant hv it on my build server